# Navigating Through HTML of a website using beautiful soup on python to select specific tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Below is the HTML of the site:
[image]

I am trying to get the python code to return the tag after the product-card__title and product-card__price, where i want it to return the name and price of the shoe.

I have tried to run the code below however, im not getting exactly what i want.

```
url = 'https://kith.com/collections/mens-footwear-sneakers'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
ex = soup.find('ul',{'class': 'collection-products'})

for i in ex.find_all('a'):
    print(i.text)
```

This is what is being returned

```
Nike Air Force 1 '07 LV8
NY vs NY




$110.00
```

And so on. I just want to be able to soup.select to the very specific tag after the class "product-card__title" or "product-card__price", for example to the adidas x Pharrell Williams Boost Slide and the $100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will print title and price of products on the page:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://kith.com/collections/mens-footwear-sneakers'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for i in soup.select('.product-card__information'):
    title = i.select_one('.product-card__title').get_text(strip=True)
    price = i.select_one('.product-card__price').get_text(strip=True)

    print(title)
    print(price)
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Nike Air Force 1 '07 LV8
$110.00
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Nike Daybreak SP
$110.00
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Nike Killshot OG SP
$90.00
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Puma Roma '68 R. Dassler Legacy
$110.00
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Puma Oslo-City R. Dassler Legacy
$120.00
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Puma Ralph Sampson Mid R. Dassler Legacy
$110.00
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Puma Ralph Sampson Lo R. Dassler Legacy
$100.00
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Puma Mirage OG R. Dassler Legacy
$100.00
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Puma Fast Rider R. Dassler Legacy
$100.00
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Y-3 Shiku Run
$350.00
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Y-3 Runner 4D
$500.00
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Y-3 Runner 4D
$500.00
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```